# Cursor solve impedance mismatch

Tags: database, object, relational-database, mismatch

I was curious when I was studying the database. Can you explain how cursor can solve impedance mismatch?
Impedance mismatch is known as an inconsistency in getting a table and accessing an object. What role does cursor have here?

I refer to Wikipedia about impedance mismatch. Please check the link below.
[WIKIPEDIA_Impedance_mismatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch)

Comment: There is no O/R impedance mismatch. Relational databases record facts, not objects. OOP is for building systems of interacting state machines, not for modeling data. The problems collectively known as the O/R impedance mismatch result from conflating both OOP and SQL with navigational databases, confusing information systems with domain simulations, implementing row-based data access on top of set-based systems, adding the complexities of caching to that mix, and more.

Comment: Thank you again for your clarification, but please answer my questions.

Comment: The solution to the O/R impedance mismatch is to really understand both OOP and the relational model and to stop following stupid industry fads. Cursors won't help with that.

Comment: I had the wrong concept. Thanks for the explanation.